# How to tell TFS not to conflict for non-checked out files?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs

I am writing code on a big project that 200 developers write code on.

When I apply "Get Latest" for solution, many conflicts appear on my local.

How can I tell TFS not to conflict for items that I did NOT check-out. Because those files belong to modules I am not interested in and I always apply "Overwrite Local File or Folder" for them.

Thank you,

Comment: They wouldn't be conflicted if they weren't changed and if they're changed it would be nice to know why you don't care about the changes. Are they compiled binaries or something else?

Comment: Yes they are changed. But I don't care about those changes because I never checked them out. They are .cs source code files.

Answer (score 0):

If the files were checked out I'd suggest you just undo all the changes on the files you aren't interested in before you execute the Get Latest operation.

However since they're not checked out, yet still changed (which I don't quite follow) then maybe try shelving the changes you *are* interested in, reset the entire workspace overwriting all changes, and then reapply your shelveset.

P.S. I still don't understand why you're changing .cs files you're not interested in, but that's a separate matter.